# Как получить подстроку из строки до определенного символа? - C#

Tags: c#, строки, подстрока

Допустим, у меня есть строка `str = "слово1^слово2^слово3^...^словоN"`.
Как мне получить "слово1"?

Можно использовать `str.Split('^')[0]`, но, мне кажется, для больших N это не совсем рационально, другие "слова" мне не нужны.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У метода `string.Split` есть перегрузка, принимающая максимальное количество подстрок для возврата:

```
var str = "слово1^слово2^слово3^...^словоN";

var words = str.Split(new char[] { '^' }, 1);

Console.WriteLine(words.Length); // 1
```

Это эффективно именно в случае больших N.

---

Уточню.

Если нужно получить *одно* первое значение, я бы взял способ из другого ответа с `Substring + IndexOf`.

Если нужно получить *несколько* первых значений, я бы взял способ `Split` с параметром count.

Answer (score 10):

Может тогда так?

```
str = "слово1^слово2...";
String word = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('^'));
```

Смотрим, где первый раз встречается разделитель, выбираем подстроку...